# Mark new post with outline, when user clicks outline disappears

Tags: php, html, css

I am developing a blog and I want to highlight new posts with a red border. Every post that is not seen by the user should be highlighted. And when you click on the post, it should lose the border. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: You should add active class with border-color

Comment: Using css and javascript, the default should be an active class red border but once clicked using javascript it removes the active class

Comment: And you might want to consider storing somewhere the fact that the user has clicked on the link to view the post. e.g. in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to use a [CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) for the links:

```css
a:link          { border: 1px solid red; }
a:visited       { border: none; }
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350030/">Topic</a>
```

Using JavaScript (cookies) and/or a database seems way overkill for a blog. When the user does not keep a history of visited sites, the CSS will not work, though.